# Accessing Visualforce static resources from local machine

Tags: visualforce, javascript, static-resources

FINAL UPDATE:

just in-case if anybody else is looking the error message solution which I was getting is due to the fact that: When you get a share link, the link points to a web page that displays the content. To get the raw content, use `?raw=1`
See https://www.dropbox.com/help/201.

so I end-up adding `?raw=1` in the url and its working fine

Hope this will help others

EDIT 2:

in VFP page I have:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.dropbox.com/....'>
```

and tried this both get the same error message

```
<script src='https://www.dropbox.com/.....'>
```

error:

> Refused to execute script from
>   'https://www.dropbox.com/...' because
>   its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type
>   checking is enabled.

EDIT:

The other option I have tried is uploading the JS file to on the web site and try accessing it from the VFP and I see that I'm getting error:

VFP:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://****/js/myjavscript.js'>
```

Error:

> 'http://****/js/myjavscript.js'. This request has been blocked; the
>   content must be served over HTTPS.

So far, I have seen all the examples that related with uploading your resource  then accessing but is that possible to have a reference on your local machine and access the resources? in my particular example I'm working with JS file that constantly needs to do changes till the development is done, I'm looking a way to make changes to JS file locally and still easily able to access in VFP

Comment: You are welcome :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a workaround, you can host *non-sensitive* JS files on a file host such as Dropbox, save the JS files in your synched folder, and link to them from your VF file with their public link.

[image]

[image]

When you save the JS file locally, your changes will automatically be synched to the online versions and will update your Visualforce page.

I've used this approach when working on JS applications before, and it works great.  The links support HTTPS, so they should be fine for your use case.

See the [Dropbox documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/help/167) for more information on linking to hosted files.

Comment: I did similar to the dropbox instead I have used my website and please see my updated question and let me know what your thoughts on the error.

Comment: Dropbox public links support HTTPS.  You should be fine.

Comment: As an example, try including https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3332104/test/test.js .  It should alert `Success!`.

Comment: did not get alert but i see `alert('Success!');`

Comment: It sounds like you didn't link to the file properly.  See e.g. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_src.asp and please update your post with your current code.

Comment: oh I understand now, I thought you ask me to click the link :)

Comment: any idea why i am getting this error `Refused to execute script from 'https://www.dropbox.com/....' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.` i have ref on vfp like this `<script src="https://www.dropbox.com.....`

Comment: Please update your post with your code.

Comment: I have updated  my question and I did tried and I able to access the JS if i copy and paste in the browser so nothing wrong with the url I got from dropbox.

Comment: Sounds like a discrepancy between our browsers.  If you go to http://jsbin.com/feyibefuyi/edit?html,output and click "Run with JS", do you get the same message?

Comment: yep i see the same error, i will post this as new question, thanks for your help

Comment: Sorry to hear it.  Sounds like you may need to find another host that supports HTTPS.

Answer (score 4):

Visualforce pages are served from a different server than your Salesforce instance. Salesforce caches static resource to make them faster to load.

Unless Salesforce can establish a link to your local machine like it can with a CDN resource, there would be no way for you to do what you ask. You might find that using a development environment like Eclipse or Sublime Text may make it easier for you upload revisions to your Javascript libraries.

Comment: I do understand the establishing a link to resource but what is the other alternative.... instead of keep uploading the JS file revisions after revisions? I have update my question, please have a look

Comment: You're going to need to upload it to someplace where Salesforce can establish a secure connection or create a secure connection with your local machine. I doubt you want to go to the trouble of establishing your machine as having that kind of security certificate. Again, I recommend working with a development environment to use as an editor for making your JS changes that can also easily upload your changes as a static resource.

Comment: If your comfortable with the command line, you may want to look into using [ant deployments](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_deploying_ant.htm). They tend to be pretty fast and allow you to use any editors you want.

Comment: @AbuHamzah. As you've edited your question to include drop box, I don't understand how synching your changes with dropbox is any different than uploading them to update a static resource using a dev environment. I recognize it's also s a matter of what you're most comfortable working with.

Comment: @crmprogdev:  the problem with uploading every time to static resource is a big pain then modifying js file from the folder which is directly sync without me uploading every time i make revision so by far the syncing option is the best in order to avoid every time upload. thanks

Comment: I understand what you're saying. It's a matter of the workflow you're comfortable with and what editors you choose to use. I get that. We all have our preferences and what we're comfortable with. Glad you found something that will work for you.